# What is the function of the braces?

Tags: eosio.cdt

in the `symbol.hpp` of the CDT I see the following definition:

```
constexpr symbol_code code() const { return symbol_code{value >> 8}; }
```

but I need a little help to understand... the method references `symbol_code` but the class that defines it (`symbol`) doesn't declare any such property.  `symbol_code` is a class, so presuming it refers to the class definition, what is the meaning of `symbol_code{...}`?

I don't understand how this works

Comment: C11 initialization syntax

Comment: I realise I should have asked this in a C++ forum instead.  thanks